# React router dom v5, Redirect to another URL onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using `React Router Dom v5`, And, I wanted to navigate from url of `localhost:3000/v3/cars` to `localhost:3000/cars` onClick.
`histiry.push()` adds at the end of current url, but doesn't change it/override it.
For example: `history.push('edit')` will change the url to `"localhost:3000/v3/cars/edit"` and not `"localhost:3000/v3/edit"`
How can I navigate to a different path?

Comment: Please read how to write a question on stack overflow and edit your question accordingly

Comment: Please update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we can't help debug code we can't see.

Answer (score 1):

In `React router dom v5` you will need to use `<Redirect/>`, it could be something like this

```
function Register () {
  const [toDashboard, setToDashboard] = React.useState(false)

  if (toDashboard === true) {
    return <Navigate to='/dashboard'/>
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <Form afterSubmit={() => setToDashboard(true)} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Check the docs on react router dom v5 about `Redirect` [here](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)

But I recommend using React router v6 anyways, Its easier with the `useNavigate`, check docs [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)

Answer (score 1):

Using React Router DOM 5.2.1, to navigate one level up '../' can be used.

```
history.push({
   pathname: '../cars'
});
```

This will help to navigate one level up to /v3/cars and replace with /cars.

Comment: to go two level up, do I need to use ../../ ?